# Project websites - Increasing visibility or wasting time?

Tags: website, projects, research-dissemination

I'm from an empirical social science background and observe that several research projects build project websites, similar to job market websites of academics. Those that I am aware of are often related to data collection projects (see for example [Ester Duflo's indian data](http://economics.mit.edu/faculty/eduflo/social)), but I guess this phenomenon exists in other [sub-]disciplines as well.

Such websites tend to do little more than give a short introduction and list the papers that were/are written in and around the project. So what is the purpose of these, if they are not to make the data publicly available? In particular:

1. Are they  an effective means to increase visibility of projects?
2. Under which circumstances does it make sense to set up such a website?
3. What makes such a website a good website?

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This answer is from computer science rather than the social sciences. However, I am not sure whether the difference matters much in this context.*

Generally, project web sites are done for the following reasons:

- Provide a **central entry point** for a given research endeavour that one can point interested people to (e.g., at conferences). Many projects lead to dozens and dozens of small and large publications distributed over many project partners, so the website of the project collects and often summarizes the main outcomes in a way that is easier to digest.
- **Advertise** the project. It is hard for a project to be successful if nobody knows that the project exists. A website is an easy means to give a "face" to an otherwise pretty amorphous construct.
- In some cases, websites have an internal, password-protected area, which the project partners use to exchange documents, discuss in forums, etc. So the website if also a sort of **collaboration tool** for project partners.
- Last but unfortunately not least, project website are often simply a **deliverable** that the funding agencies expect / require, so they need to be done no matter if it having one serves any concrete goal outside of its mere existence.

That being said, there are of course plenty of websites that are simply useless. The thing is, it is hard to say in advance whether a website will actually be useful for a specific project or not. You may often think in the beginning of the project that you will need a website e.g., as a discussion and dissemination platform, but then nobody ends up using it and it slides into general uselessness.

To answer your questions:

> Are they an effective means to increase visibility of projects?

Maybe, but only if they are very well done and linked in a highly visible way. I would say most websites are not particularly effective in terms of visibility, even though this is typically one of the main goals.

> Under which circumstances does it make sense to set up such a website?

I will always set up at least a rudimentary website. Doing a simple website is close to no effort, and having one (even a simple one) is usually better than having none at all.

> What makes such a website a good website?

This is hard to answer without knowing what specifically the website should do for a project. I assume you mean primarily as a dissemination tool - in that context, what you really need is **high-quality content** (which is targeted at whatever your audience is), **fresh content** (try to have a regular schedule, e.g., a monthly research blog), **personal touch** (photos from meetings, opinion pieces, ...), **highly visible linking** (the way how Google and other search engines work is that they assume that website linked from important websites are also important, so you need to get your website linked from other highly ranked sites, so as to improve your page rank), and **pleasing visuals** (make sure that your website is technically up to date).

Comment: Another possibility: if I find an interesting paper a few years old, I would be interested in knowing if the authors have made any updates. Their webpage, if the layout is clear, is my first stop, and "articles that cite this article" the second.

Comment: @Davidmh: I don't think an *author* website is the same as a *project* website. Moreover, as you are mentioning a timespan of "a few years", having a website during the runtime of a project is one possibility, but maintaining the website online after the project has ended, when there is no more funding for paying for hosting or a domain, and possibly none of the people who worked on the project still employed by any of the participating institutions, is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 3):

You have omitted one crucial reason for setting a project website.

**It is mandatory to set up a website for the project by the funding agency**.

This is true for most EU projects I know of and usually the project website is also a separate deliverable delivered early (months 2-5) in the beginning of the project. This is good for everyone (project partners, project officer, reviewer) because it shows that the project has taken off, especially in the first few months where there are no other deliverables to show.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers state, they serve useful purposes both internally and externally. Specially if the proyect is longer running.

But setting up and maintaining a good website is work. You'd have an assistant with the task to keep it up, pester people to enter their papers, do write up the meetings and keep up their worklogs.

Comment: If only, I had this "assistant" for doing those menial jobs. Sorry to say, but many times, even these kind of jobs are done by the main developers of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

As these answers show, there are a lot of reasons to set up a project website.

Addressing your third question is a bit more difficult and many projects plan-behind on their website, causing it to feel more like a nuisance than an asset.  At the very basic level, a project website should be designed for the specific project and aid in the success of that project.  It should serve as the nexus of all communication for the project and be incorporated into the everyday workflow.  If you're working with it every day, it's also less likely to be out-of-date.

A few guidelines that I would suggest:

**Required:**

- Public and restricted sections
- Mobile friendly (Who hasn't had an idea when nowhere near a computer?)
- Document version control (Email chains with file attachments rank somewhere between torture and mutilation)
- Database access point (Don't lug your data around in Excel files)
- Easy input area for notes and worklogs.
- Restricted discussion board and schedule.  (Seems odd until you try to lean on memories of old conversations)

**Optional:**

- Public discussion board
- Visualizations of data
- Links to similar/related projects
- Upload point for any data/files generated elsewhere.
- Workflow/Issue tracking (Especially if collaborating with distant colleagues)

My biggest suggestion would be to sneak into the nearby CS department and kidnap a Web guru as early in the project as possible.  Have the entire team outline the project and discuss what a website could do to help keep everything organized.  Then, make sure the site is easy to update/maintain and be sure everyone knows how to work with it.

Comment: This sounds like a lot and probably not something for one of those research projects everyone has 2-3 of and which involve only 3-5  co-authors. But I guess that's a little bit specific to the different sciences.

Comment: Good websites take a bit of work to plan and set up, but a small site can be just as helpful as a big one.  Keeping 2 or 3 teams of 5 organized can add a lot of little administrative tasks that unnecessarily eat up time.  Once you have a good idea of a setup that works well for a small project, it's almost trivially easy to copy that code to a new site for a similar project.